# Find a sub-string within a buffer inside a Linux kernel function

Tags: c, linux, string, linux-kernel, kernel

I'm new to Linux kernel development, and I have a question that I don't think has been addressed previously:

> How do you find a sub-string within a buffer inside a kernel function?

Imagine that I read in a decently size file to a buffer (`ls -lart` says the file size is around 3000). I would like to find, and print the line where a sub-string exists within that buffer. Because we are in the kernel, most standard `stdio.h` or `string.h` functions like `strstr` or `fgets` are not available. So many current stack overflow questions like: [Check substring exists in a string in C](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12784766/check-substring-exists-in-a-string-in-c/12784812) are not as valid. However, I did find a question like: [Check for substring in a buffer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13848310/check-for-substring-in-a-buffer), but is using `memmem()` the best alternative? While I can cheat, and manually hard code where in the buffer I'm looking, it's not the programmer way.

Comment: I'm pretty sure that the kernel provides most of the string functions, including `strstr`.

Comment: And it's "Thanks in advance!", not "Thanks in advanced!".

Comment: When I, try to include `string.h`, I get an error saying no such file or directory. Apparently, unless I specifically include it as a `-I` in the `gcc` compile, it's not explicitly added. It makes me think it's not how it should be done...

Comment: That's not the right header. Hang on, let me `grep` the kernel sources.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`strstr` *is* available in the Linux kernel. It's declared in `linux/string.h`.

However, using `memmem` could possibly be safer if the buffer that you've read the "file" into isn't nul-terminated.

If you want to search for a full line, you can add `\n` to the beginning and end of the string that you're searching for.

Alternatively, if you don't want to include the full line that you want to search, you can rewind (using a `char` pointer or similar) to the `\n` before the result of `strstr`.

If you want to print this string, use `printk` from `linux/printk.h`. It's similar to `printf` except that it has a few extensions to the `%p` format -- though you probably won't have to bother with printing pointers.

Comment: ah! That makes sense - I thought it strange that string manipulation wouldn't be available in the kernel. Quite an easy answer.

May I expand your answer - how would you best print the line that matches a substring within the buffer?

Comment: @BillyThorton `kprint`, I believe.

Comment: Sorry, not the function to perform the printing. I'm asking how you would loop through the buffer to match the line with the substring. Using `strstr` you can find existence, but a bit trickier when you want the full line that matches.

Comment: @BillyThorton I would say add `\n` to the beginning and end of the string that you're searching for.

Comment: And just use the full line as the substring, rather than just a substring within that line?

Comment: @BillyThorton Yeah. Although you *could* rewind to the byte just after the `\n`.

Comment: Where would rewind be? Since `stdio.h`, like `string.h` is hidden in another linux include file, and file streams in the kernel aren't the same as in userland (as the `filp` function demonstrates?

Comment: @BillyThorton Not the `rewind` function. Just decrement the pointer until it points to `\n`, and then increment it again.